# Why doesn't strtod work in the correct way?

Tags: c, string

I am coding in Code-Blocks Editor with GNU GCC Compiler.I tried to use function `strtod` which the below prototype:

`double strtod(const char *a, char **b);`

If I use the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    char *a;
    a="99.5HELLO";
    char *b;
    printf("%.1lf\n%s", strtod(a, &b), b);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the Console Terminal to represent something like this after running the code:

```
99.5
HELLO
```

But what I actually got was something strange:

```
99.5
@
```

What's happening? Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified, and so the last function argument may be evaluated first and you end up reading the uninitialized value `b`, which is undefined behaviour.

Order the evaluations:

```
const char *a = "99.5HELLO";
char *b;
double d = strtod(a, &b);

printf("%.1f\n%s", d, b);
```

Comment: Some notes: 1) string literals are immutable; refer to them via `const char*`. 2) `%lf` is the same as `%f`, the `l` has no effect for floating point conversions (not to be confused with `L`!).